# how to make the connection between sclate,the servlet and classes

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalatra, scalate

I'm new with the architecture of scalatra and devloppement scala .. i want to do a project with these new technilogies with templates but the problem that I can not understand how to realize the connection between the class or object, the servlet and Scalate..

I followed the site Scalate http://scalate.fusesource.org/ but I think it is not as easy..
I wanted to make html page and servlet with well-specified classes (like jsp,servlet and class java) but I unknown if faissable and If I to follow in this way the architecture of scalatra.

Can someone help me with documentation or explain to me how to do..I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [scalatra-http-client](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-website-examples/tree/master/2.2/http/scalatra-http-client) working example published by Scalatra in Github. It's the bare minimum you need and can't get any easier than this.

The next step is to take a look at the other [scalatra-website-examples](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-website-examples/tree/master/2.2/http) webapp implemented examples that demonstrate things like: authentication, file uploading, forms handling and all this nicely wrapped with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the [Getting started guide](http://scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/). By following this guide, you create a SBT build definition which is based on the [scalatra-sbt.g8 Template](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt.g8). This already includes a setup for scalatra-scalate. The build definition encodes the project structure, dependencies and build characteristics. It allows SBT for example to download all dependencies and compile your project.

Then there are SBT plugins to create IDE projects for all common IDEs: [sbt-eclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse), [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea).

Here is explained how to use them with a Scalatra project: [IDE Support](http://scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/ide-support.html). Note that IDEA for example can directly import SBT or Maven projects.